# Distance of a particle; a function its time

Tags: functions, physics

> *Force* is a function of *mass* and *acceleration*. Here *mass* is a fundamental quantity, and *acceleration* is a derived quantity OR $F(a, m) = ma$.

I want to ask that why the distance traveled by a particle is only the function of $time$? While, $S = vt$. Where $S$ is the distance traveled, $v$ is the velocity and $t$ is the time. Why is it not a function of its velocity too? Here *time* is a fundamental quantity and *velocity* is a derived quantity as in the case of force. Also *Force* is directly proportional to *mass* as *distance* is directly proportional to *time*.

Comment: Who said distance is just a function of time?

Comment: In my elementary calculus book, its written: $s(t)$ = distance traveled by a particle from time $0$ to $t$.

Comment: That does not make it a function of 'just' time.it is just defining a notation it is gonna use in further explanations.

Comment: I think if $v$ is constant, then the distance traveled by the particle is just the function of it's time. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a particle trajectory then at each point in time the particle has traveled a precise distance, but given a certain value for velocity there may be more than one point on the particle's trajectory where the particle was traveling at that velocity, thus the velocity at a pont in the the trajectory does not determine the distance the particle has traveled. However, if the particle is traveling say with constant acceleration than this would be a case where the distance traveled is a function of velocity.

Comment: You mean, if the particle doesn't experience any acceleration or its moving in a straight line with constant velocity, then the distance traveled by it is not a function of it's velocity but only it's time?

Comment: I just mean at many points in the particle's trajectory the particle may be traveling at the same velocity, thus by just knowing the velocity alone you wouldn't be able to determine the distance traveled. But on the contrary at each point in time the particle has traveled a unique distance, thus the distance traveled is a function of time.

Answer (score 0):

$$S(v, T)= \int_{0}^{T}v(t)dt$$
So really, distance is not proportional to time in general, and is proportional only if  $v$ is a constant, i.e. $S=vt$ is only true if $v$ is constant.

$S$ is a function of $v$ and $T$.

Comment: If $v$ is constant, then is the distance traveled by the particle the function of it's time only?

Comment: If velocity doesn't remain constant, then there must be acceleration. So in a way, $S$ is a function of $a$ and $t$.